# Can I find my page on the Users page?

Tags: support, pagination, users-page

Is there a way to find my page on the users page / jump over there?

Comment: You mean by which of the pages you would normally/currently turn up on?

Comment: There are showing the first 30 users on page 1, and next on page 2....
I wonder on what page am I in....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you can't. Obviously it is sort of a binary search, and it is quite a hassle when you have low reputation.

If you do not need up to date accuracy or just want a good guess for a starting point, look at the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/data-dump-sandbox). Get your position in there and divide by 35 (Thanks, Chris).

Comment: This is so cool... great idea !!
I'll play with it in my spare (no existing) time.
Thanks.

Comment: Divide by 35 - the users page is a 5 x 7 grid

Comment: well... and the answer is somewhere around page 223.

Comment: Yeh, I did... I've rechecked.. thanks !

Answer (score 3):

As of today, you are on [page #261](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=261).

Comment: You are right.. how come it is not the results from :
select count(*) from users where reputation >= 571
and divide it by 35.... (7810) = 223... +/- 1 page?

Comment: The datadump has a certain age. Much has happened in the meantime, I would say.

Comment: I see, so I wonder how @mouviciel found me, as I'm sure he didn't look it up page by page...

Comment: I took a random page, say 1000. You can set this in the URL field of your browser. Then I tried 500, 200, 300, 250, also by changing URL. Finally, I looked up with navigation buttons at bottom-right.

Comment: How to catch a lion in a desert :-) thanks, Should have done it myself...

Comment: From now on, you can track your page easily: you've moved from 261 to 257.